# Javascriptexecutor is not working while running through safari webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to perform a click using javascriptexecutor.

```
JavasciptExecutor jse=(JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
jse.executescript("arguments[0].click();",webelement)
```

While running from safari,it is showing "`undefined is not a function<evaluating arguments[0].click` "
Same works fine in chrome driver.

Am I need to add any capabilities while initiating webDriver?
I have already added `capabilities.SetJavascriptEnabled(true)`. Still it is not working

Comment: Can you provide the site and some additional code, for example how you retrieve the WebElement?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the capabilities of driver browserwise.

When running the testcases in safari browser set a global flag for browser. You can create a config file and add "safari" or "chrome" when running it through safari or chrome.

In your source initialize your driver for safari like below :

```
 if (browser.equals("safari")) {
        SafariOptions safariOptions = new SafariOptions();
        safariOptions.setUseCleanSession(true);
        safariOptions.setUseTechnologyPreview(true);
        driver = new SafariDriver(safariOptions);

    }
```

Then navigate to your desired url. Here i am adding a sample source for your understanding.

```
 driver.get("https://www.google.com");

 WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.className("gb_P"));
 jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elem);
```

Hope this will solve your issue. Feel free to comment here for more information.